# JSF1005: Cannot instantiate validator of type javax.faces.Bean

Tags: css, jsf-2, richfaces

I am getting error below on every action after migrating from JSF 1.2 and RF 3.3 to JSF 2.1 and RF 4. Also my CSS styles is not as to be. I think my CSS problem can related to this issue.

```
23.Ara.2011 23:03:42 com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl createValidator
SEVERE: JSF1005: Cannot instantiate validator of type javax.faces.Bean
```

I search on the net but couldn't find any solution.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webapp's runtime classpath is dirty.

This is a pretty generic problem which can not have a single suitable answer without having a complete overview of all libraries supplied in the webapp deploy. My best guess would be that you've placed RichFaces source code JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib`. RichFaces ships with separate JAR files for the binary classes and for the source code. You should not put RichFaces source code JAR files (the ones with a filename ending on `-source`) in the classpath. Remove them and keep the binary JAR files. The source code JAR files contain in turn also several startup scripts. They should not be executed twice.

As to the CSS problem, this is likely unrelated. RichFaces loads CSS through the new JSF2 `<h:head>` component. Make sure that you have in your (master) template(s) a `<h:head>` instead of `<head>`.

Comment: Hi BalusC thank you for your reply.  I have this jars in my WEB-INF/lib.  I didnt place RF sorucode Jar files.  My web inf libs are below.  Could you pls have a look.  ant-antlr.jar
antlr-runtime.jar
antlr.jar
common-annotations.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-logging.jar
cssparser-0.9.5.jar
dom4j.jar
guava-r09.jar
hibernate-annotations.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
hibernate-core.jar
hibernate-entitymanager.jar
hibernate-search.jar
hibernate-validator.jar
javassist.jar
javax.faces-2.1.4.jar

Comment: mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar
persistence-api.jar
richfaces-components-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
jsf-tlds.jar
jstl.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jta.jar
log4j.jar
lucene-core.jar
richfaces-components-ui-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-api-4.1.0.Final.jar
richfaces-core-impl-4.1.0.Final.jar
sac-1.3.jar
slf4j-api.jar
slf4j-log4j12.jar
standard.jar

Comment: Which appserver impl/version exactly are you using? Tomcat?

Comment: yes apache-tomcat-6.0.18.   By the way I my CSS files are included in the h:head and when I check with firefox web developer plugin I can see that my css file is loaded.

Comment: JSF 2.1 requires servlet 3.0. Upgrade to Tomcat 7 and update webapp's `web.xml` to comply servlet 3.0.

Comment: Hi BalusC I did what you say.  Upgrade to tomcat 7 and update my `web.xml` file.  But unfortunately the result is the same.  I create a new project with another name with jsf 2.0 and web 3.0 spec. Then copy my files to that project.  When I run that project I surprisingly see that the error I gave above occured.  That make me think if it may be due to my libs.  But I don't know how and which?

Comment: I reread the list of your libs again, the `jsf-tlds.jar` look very suspicious. Where did you get it from? Remove it. TLDs are supposed to be already inside the `javax.faces` JAR file.

Comment: Hi BalusC I finally found the reason.  `<rich:graphValidator>` has caused this error.  I remove that components and the issue resolved.  By the way I also drop jsf-tld.jar.  Thank you so much for your guide.