# Help <f:validateBean /> - Cannot instantiate validator of type javax.faces.Bean

Tags: jsf, tomcat7, hibernate-validator

Hi Guys can anyone help me out I am having problems setting up bean validation in my web project.

I have read the following questions that i suspect that their is a problem in my jar files but I am not sure which one. Can anyone point out the cause of this conflict.

[Why  won't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8508984/why-fvalidatebean-wont-work)

[JSF1005: Cannot instantiate validator of type javax.faces.Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620671/jsf1005-cannot-instantiate-validator-of-type-javax-faces-bean)

**Stack Trace**

```
Jun 25, 2014 11:20:42 AM com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl createValidator
SEVERE: JSF1005: Cannot instantiate validator of type javax.faces.Bean
Jun 25, 2014 11:20:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [facesServlet] in context with path [/CorpSoaBackOffice2] threw exception [Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.Bean not found.] with root cause
javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Named Object: javax.faces.Bean not found.
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createValidator(ApplicationImpl.java:1596)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.createValidator(OmniApplication.java:115)
    at org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowApplication.createValidator(FlowApplication.java:169)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.createValidator(OmniApplication.java:115)
    at com.sun.faces.component.validator.ComponentValidators.addValidatorsToComponent(ComponentValidators.java:282)
    at com.sun.faces.component.validator.ComponentValidators.addValidators(ComponentValidators.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.processValidators(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:621)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.privateOnComponentPopulated(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:217)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.applyWrapping(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ValidatorTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:86)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:106)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:395)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:366)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:111)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.applyNextHandler(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.apply(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:203)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.apply(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:120)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:219)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:312)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:371)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:350)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:199)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:169)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:95)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.buildView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:995)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.bdo.ces.utilities.jsf.NoCacheFilterImpl.doFilter(NoCacheFilterImpl.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.bdo.ces.utilities.jsf.IECompatibleJsfPagesFilterImpl.doFilter(IECompatibleJsfPagesFilterImpl.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1686)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

**My lib**

```
antlr-2.7.7.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.0.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.0.jar
bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar
bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar
bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar
ces-theme.jar
classmate-1.0.0.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
commons-collections-2.1.jar
commons-digester-1.7.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
gson-2.2.4.jar
hibernate-c3p0-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.5.Final.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.1.1.Final.jar
itext-4.2.1.jar
jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar
jasperreports-3.5.3.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
jcommon-1.0.15.jar
jdtcore-3.1.0.jar
jfreechart-1.0.12.jar
jsf-api-2.2.5.jar
jsf-impl-2.2.5.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jul-to-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar
logback-classic-1.1.2.jar
logback-core-1.1.2.jar
mchange-commons-java-0.2.3.4.jar
ognl-2.6.11.jar
omnifaces-1.7.jar
pdf-renderer-1.0.5.jar
poi-3.10-FINAL.jar
primefaces-5.0.jar
primefaces-extensions-2.0.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-binding-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-faces-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-js-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-js-resources-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-acl-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-config-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-taglibs-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webflow-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar
sqljdbc4.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
xml-apis-1.3.02.jar
```

**Tomcat 7.0.39 lib (The one we have in prod)**

```
tomcat-util.jar
annotations-api.jar
catalina.jar
catalina-ant.jar
catalina-ha.jar
catalina-tribes.jar
ecj-4.2.1.jar
el-api.jar
jasper.jar
jasper-el.jar
jsp-api.jar
servlet-api.jar
tomcat-api.jar
tomcat-coyote.jar
tomcat-dbcp.jar
tomcat-i18n-es.jar
tomcat-i18n-fr.jar
tomcat-i18n-ja.jar
tomcat-jdbc.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this time the problem was not my fault but a bug with the Mojarra (Jsf-impl) jar.

[Bean validation doesn't work with mojarra 2.2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637996/bean-validation-doesnt-work-with-mojarra-2-2-4)

I tried the solution there by creating a servletContextListener. Which works but I also found that the problem can be solved by just updating to the latest version where the bug is already fixed.

jsf-api-2.2.5.jar ---> jsf-api-2.2.7.jar

jsf-impl-2.2.5.jar ---> jsf-impl-2.2.7.jar